# Como fazer um POST com um HttpEntity no formato correto?

Tags: java, api, spring, rest

Bom dia,

Estou realizando um `POST` para uma `API` utilizando o `HttpEntity` do `Spring`, porém não tenho certeza se o `POST` que estou realizando está sendo feito da forma correta, e estou tendo erros ao criar uma sessão a partir disto.

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity <String> (token + "&flag=1", httpHeaders);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            log.info("\nParametros da sessão:");
            log.info("\n" + sessionService);
            log.info("\n" + httpEntity);
            SessionResponse sessao = restTemplate.postForObject(sessionService, httpEntity, SessionResponse.class);
            log.info("\nSessão: " + sessao);
            if(sessao==null) {

                log.info("\n:::checking Session: sessao nula");

                return null;
            }

            return sessao;
        }catch(HttpServerErrorException e) {
            log.info(":::checking Session: erro " + token);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

No código acima estou caindo na `HttpServerErrorException` então é provável que este POST esteja incorreto.

Ao "Printar" a `httpEntity` eu tenho um retorno neste formato:

```
<token&flag=1,{Content-Type=[text/html]}>
```

Estou com duvida se esses caracteres(<>) estão corretos.

Alguém saberia me dizer se estou fazendo algo aparentemente errado ?

Alguns dos erros dessa chamada:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:437)
        at br.com.consiste.conteudos.backend.controllers.CMSController.firstSession(CMSController.java:1504)
        at br.com.consiste.conteudos.backend.controllers.CMSController.getSessao(CMSController.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: E qual a stacktrace?

Comment: adicionei no post os retornos